# The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am working on a react-native app in Jan 2023 the app was building successfully and today I am trying to make a build but the build is crashing with below error 1, I have also re-setup my react native env after that, I have built 2 or 3 apps after that and they build.

#### Versions

```
 ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.4"
        kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
    }
```

#### Error 1

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1.
     AAR metadata file: /home/xyz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d7be3d1450d870047b15ae8f44694206/transformed/jetified-appcompat-resources-1.6.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

When I increase the **compileSdkVersion to 33** it gave me this error 2

#### Versions

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.4"
kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
```

#### Error 2

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/xyz/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1ab3f973c5a5d473246b969002b3ea52/transformed/material-1.8.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

I also tried many solutions like changing different versions, and changing gradle versions and adding other libraries by solutions of StackOverflow and other links but nothing worked.

#### Android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.4"
        kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

#### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: Are you updating any libraries related to androidx/ material? Also, what's the gradle plugin and gradle version you are running?

Comment: No, i didn't updated any Library after i get this error then i did changes many times to gradle qnd also added som libraries which was given on internet as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update this line **com.android.tools.build:gradle** in **android/build.gradle** to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

also update

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33       <== 33 version
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.4"
        kotlin_version = "1.8.0"    <=== this if you have different version
    }
```

and also updated **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** 7.4

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```